# How to design a binary classifier to output 1 and -1 in Keras

Tags: keras

I am designing a binary classifier in Keras which is expected to output `1` and `-1` for each input. If the output is `0` or `1`, I could use `binary_crossentropy` as the loss function. I thought the story won't change when I change the output to `1` and `-1`, but the performance was not good. Does that mean the loss function `binary_crossentropy` only works on `0` and `1` labels?

I know there exists an alternative way to solve this problem since even for the `0` and `1` case, the output of the last layer is indeed ranging from `0` and `1`. So I could do the rescale for the output to satisfy the `-1` and `1` requirement, but if I could figure out a way to simply output `-1` and `1`, it would be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cross-entropy uses the fact that all elements (except by one) in the target vector y are 0 to nullify the gradient on all activations that are not the correct one, adding stability to the process.

You can either:

1. use `tanh` activation (outputs in the [-1, 1] range) and `mse` loss:

```
x = Input(...)

y = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
y = Dense(128, activation='relu')(y)
y = Dense(1, activation='tanh')(y)

model = Model(inputs=x, outputs=y)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

# train model using labels in {-1, 1}
# outputs values are in [-1, 1]
```

2. Train the sigmoid and scale your logits. This seems more reasonable to me:

```
x = Input(...)

y = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
y = Dense(128, activation='relu')(y)
y = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(y)

model = Model(inputs=x, outputs=y)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')

# train model using labels in {0, 1}

z = Lambda(lambda _y: _y / 2 + .5)(y)
model = Model(inputs=x, outputs=z)

# outputs values are in [-1, 1]
```

**Note:** if you are trying to distinguish two things in space with a Siamese network (e.g. distinguish if two images contain the same object), then take a look at contrastive-loss definition at [mnist-siamese example](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_siamese.py). My experience is that it works much better than any `sigma`/`tanh` output.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the `binary_corssentropy` only works on 0 and 1 labels. Suppose the two classes are cat and dog, here we have an observation data X1 labeled as cat, We can regard the labels as the ground-truth class probabilities y=(1.0,0)T, notice that the 1st element in the probability distribution represents the probability of the input data being class 1, absolutely cat in this case. and the model predicted a different distribution, say y^ = (0.8,0.2), and we need to adjust the parameters to make y^ closer to y. and we use `binary_crossentropy` to measure the difference between y and y^. 
[image: Cross Entropy]

H(y,y^) is the cross-entropy.

I use Keras with Tensorflow as backend, I found [tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits) was called bechind `binary_crossentropy` in Keras.

According to the formulations in the introduction to sigmoid_cross_entropy of tensorflow, the label should only be a real number ranged from (0,1), the labels represent ground-truth probability distribution, usually in observations the probability is 0 and 1.

Wish it helps.